# GeoServer not running on port :8080 on Windows 7?

Tags: geoserver, installation, windows-7

After Installing GeoServer on my windows machine, then I restarted tomcat but it doesn't start.

Before installing the geoserver localhost:8080 is working.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. What error you are getting ? Which version you are using ? Please check http://docs.geoserver.org/2.2.4/user/installation/windows/installer.html

Comment: Might be port problem .Turn off the IIS (which I think installed on 8080 port OR install geoserver on different port i.e 8082 etc. )

Comment: Do you have a firewall running? I have had to open the specific port in Windows firewall when I had faced such an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on port 8080.  Switching to 8000 worked for me......at least it still is working.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off your firewall and see if the problem goes away. if so, open that port in the firewall.

If not, 8080 is used by a lot of applications, you probably have something installed that is using that port

either way, it would be advisable to change the geoserver port to somethimg obscure and ensure that it gets opened through the firewall

Answer (score -2):

geoserver Web archive helps: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/war.html. I follow the instruction and everything works out.

Comment: Links can change or disappear over time.  Please include the steps that worked for you in your answer

Comment: First reply ever over here. Thank for reminding. Will try to be more helpful next time!!

Answer (score -3):

unistall your geoserver and re-install it with another port number. for example 8090, it should be work.

Comment: Hello :-) The approach is rather crude. You should be able to assign a new port number in a config file and then restart the service.

Comment: Hello.. i had this problem too and i changed the number of ports and now it works!